# Нет изображения после установки firmware

Tags: linux, графика, драйвер, amd

Черный экран. Нет никакого изображения, даже консоли после установки фирмваре.

Пробовал Linux 4.19.0 и 5.3.0 на Debian 10

```
cpu: AMD A6-7480 Radeon R5, 8 Compute Cores 2C+6G


00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev e6)
```

Подключился по ссх и увидел что xrandr не правильно показывает разъёмы

```
DISPLAY=:0 xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

На плате только Dsub. F2A68HM-S1

в dmesg ещё

```
[    1.614589] [drm] Unsupported Connector type:5!
```

Comment: Asus A68HM-K, AMD A6 7480 - так же черный экран после установки, liveCD работает нормально...

Comment: Мой совет не получился?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пофиксил через GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.dc=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1"

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105880